# Converting text read from PDF into a usable format for unnest_tokens?

Tags: r

I have a series of PDFs that I need to mine for data (e.g. frequency of words and topic modelling). It's pretty simple to read each one into R using `pdf_text`. For example, I have used the following code successfully: `document1 <- pdf_text("document1.pdf") %>% strsplit("\n")` but that gives me a list of character vectors of unequal length. It looks like this:

```
    str(publicboard123july1)
    List of 97
    $ : chr [1:35] "                Meeting of the Board" "                              
    July 12-13, 2012" "           A meeting of the Board" " the offices 
    of the Board of" ...
    $ : chr [1:26] "XXXXX" "                    NAME 1" "                    
    $ : chr [1:49] "
```

I've used the examples posted on stack overflow to convert the list into a matrix. For example, this works: `document1 <- data.frame(t(sapply(document1,c)))`

However, whenever i try to get `unnest_tokens` to work, I get the following response: `Error in check_input(x) : 
  Input must be a character vector of any length or a list of character
  vectors, each of which has a length of 1.`

I have tried literally every way I can find to turn the list into a data_frame (all of these work) but then every time I try to unnest the words, I get the same response. Can anyone help? Also, I have to do this for over 1000 documents so if you have code that I could use in a loop, that would be incredible.

I'm new to R so let me know if there's anything I've forgotten to add and I'll add it as an edit. Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tested with a PDF file on my disk, the following did what the question is asking for.

Assign the name of the file to be read to `doc1`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)
library(pdftools)

document1 <- pdf_text(doc1) %>% strsplit("\n")

document1 %>%
  unlist() %>%
  trimws() %>%
  tibble(txt = .) %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, txt)
```

The code above starts with the data as read in like in the question. The code below is much simpler and does the same. The main point is to avoid `strsplit`, this is what `unnest_tokens` is meant for.

```
document1  <- pdf_text(doc1) %>%
  tibble(txt = .) %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, txt)
```

Comment: @NewtoRcode Thanks. See the edit, the code is much simpler now.

Comment: And it will be easy to make reproducible now too! Thanks again - you're the best!